# Using ASP.NET Web API with Twilio instead of ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I got the Twilio ASP.NET example working for Twilio receiving a call.  I am trying to develop a console app using the ASP.NET Web API instead of the ASP.NET MVC Controller class used in the example.  We do not want to host the ASP.NET MVC application on an ISS Server and want the console app to run "locally".

Being new to ASP.NET and the web api, I use online examples to setup the website in the Main() function using VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Web.Http.SelfHost
Imports System.Web.Http

Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        'Try config as localhost/ with port number
    Dim config As New HttpSelfHostConfiguration("https://localhost:9032")


    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name:="DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )

    Using server As New HttpSelfHostServer(config)
        Try
            server.OpenAsync().Wait()
            Console.WriteLine("Listening.")
        Catch aggEx As AggregateException
            Console.WriteLine("Error opening server.")

        End Try

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop listening and exit.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Using

End Sub
```

End Module

Per an online example, I created a Controller folder and created a class file called VoiceControll.vb with the following code:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports Twilio.AspNet.Mvc
Imports Twilio.TwiML

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class VoiceController
        Inherits TwilioController
        'Inherits ApiController

        '<HttpPost>
        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Dim response = New VoiceResponse()
          response.Say("Hello.  This is Twilio.")
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        response.Play(digits:="1")
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        response.Hangup()
        Return TwiML(response)
    End Function

End Class
```

End Namespace

This is basically the code from the example.  I am not sure what function name to use for the Twilio post function (receiving a call) or if ActionResult works in the ASP.NET Web api.

I then start the console app in admin mode with no errors.  I then run the ngrok command ngrok http -host-header="localhost:9032" 9032 and get the web url to change the http post url on the Twilio console for my Twilio phone number.

To test, I call the Twilio number and receive the message "An application error has occurred.".  The Twilio debug on the console shows a 502 http error.

My feeling is that my function name or something in the controller code is incorrect.

I've tried using the Twilio ASP.NET web api example by Long Le.

Like I said earlier, I am new to ASP.NET and feel that I made a stupid mistake in the code.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried making an HTTP request directly to your application on localhost:9032 using something like `curl` or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)? It would be best to ensure that your application is responding correctly before pointing the Twilio number at it.